# Одинаковые записи в промежуточной таблицей

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы: `Users`, `Moods`. Есть связующая таблица `UserMoods` (связь "Many-To-Many"), выглядит схема так - https://ibb.co/R675tb6.

Записи в `UserMoods` выглядят так - https://ibb.co/rG9jTP3.

Вопрос: могу ли я в такую таблицу добавить строку, у которой поля будут `userId = 3`, `moodId = 2`, то есть такие значения, которые уже существуют?

Postgres говорит, что нельзя, но мне надо хранить такие записи, как можно это решить? Или использовать другую связь между таблицами?

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UserMoods_userId_moodId_key"
DETAIL:  Key ("userId", "moodId")=(3, 2) already exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

postgresql прямым текстом говорит, что у вас определено уникальное ограничение (вами собственноручно, а не базой) `UserMoods_userId_moodId_key`, которое препятствует добавлять повторяющиеся строки с ключом `Key ("userId", "moodId")` из двух полей. Это ограничение допускает комбинации `(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3)` но не `(3,2), (3,2)`. Вполне резонное ограничение для таблицы связей многие-ко-многим.

Если вам это ограничение не нужно - ну так уберите его, вы же сами его добавили.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу убрать это ограничение?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то ограничения уже сняты https://ibb.co/tQSB3FR

Comment: обычный `alter table .. drop constraint ..`